# Cleaning up after a Scotty application is terminated

Tags: haskell, scotty

I have a Scotty application that listens on a Unix socket. I’d like the application to delete the socket when it exits (i.e. when I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>), but I’m not sure how to accomplish this. My `main` function looks like

```
main = do
    sock <- socket AF_UNIX Stream 0
    bind sock $ SockAddrUnix "/tmp/my_app.sock"
    listen sock maxListenQueue

    scottySocket def sock $ do
        ...

    removeFile "/tmp/my_app.sock"
```

When I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> the `removeFile` function is not called—that seems to be an interrupt that the Scotty framework does not or cannot catch. Is there any way to perform cleanup actions like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest principled way probably is using [`bracket`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:bracket) from `Control.Exception`:

```
main = bracket acquireSock cleanupSock $ \(sock, _) -> do
    listen sock maxListenQueue
    scottySocket def sock $ do
        ...
    where
    -- Acquiring the resource.
    acquireSock = do
        sock <- socket AF_UNIX Stream 0
        let sockPath = "/tmp/my_app.sock"
        bind sock $ SockAddrUnix sockPath
        return (sock, sockPath)
    -- Releasing the resource.
    cleanupSock (sock, sockPath) = do
        removeFile sockPath
        close sock
```